# When scrolling down, how do I make it so it overlaps my video?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: image[1]]

so I want to make it so when I scroll down the div from under it slowly overlaps the video as I'm scrolling down. sort of like the Minecraft home website

Answer (score 0):

Will take a mix of `z-index` and `position:fixed` to get what you're aiming for...

```css
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<h1>Some Heading</h1>

<div style="position:relative;height:auto;background-color:lightblue;font-size:20px; margin:50% 5%">
  Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div style="position:relative;height:auto;background-color:lightpink;font-size:16px; margin:40% 5%;">
  Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>
```